# Crash - Runtime exception (MultiDex.java:178)

Tags: android, runtime, android-multidex

I have a issue with application class, is a Runtime exception so I can't find how replicate, maybe some people here can help me with this problem. I think that maybe is the device or android in self, but I need to be sure, if anyone can help me, i going to be grateful.
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Android version: 4.4
Stacktrace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:516) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication
>   (ActivityThread.java:4514) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500
>   (ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1381)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5299) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:825) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:641) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native
>   Method)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:  at
>   android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install (MultiDex.java:178) at
>   app.tacoguru.MultiDexApplication.attachBaseContext
>   (MultiDexApplication.java:35) at android.app.Application.attach
>   (Application.java:181) at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication
>   (Instrumentation.java:991) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:975)
>   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:511)

MultidexApplication code lines:

```
public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {

    public MultiDexApplication() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Apptentive.register(this, key);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return super.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true 
}
```

Comment: According to [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/marshmallow-release/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.java#178), `RuntimeException` on line 178 just rethrows inner exception that has information about the root cause. Can you look again in your logs (search for `Multidex installation failure` string) and share the inner exception stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing this line `MultiDex.install(this);` and inherit your `Application` class from `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application`.

Comment: I already done that suggestion, but apptentive library crashes
Following the documentation in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
I am using the third option to enable Multidex funcionality.

Comment: Can you remove this line and try: `Apptentive.register(this, key);`

Comment: I cannot because that code line is part from Apptentive Library
https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android/blob/master/samples/apptentive-example/src/main/java/com/apptentive/android/example/ExampleApplication.java